# famo.us click generates two events Mouseevent and CustomEvent - overlayed surfaces

Tags: famo.us

I have encountered surfaces for which onlick famo.us randomly generates CustomEvent or Mouseevent or in some cases both. How does this work?

[image]

Surface B is as wide as its radius and has a transform (10, 280, 2)
Surface A's width is 320 and has a transform (0,0,1)

When I click on Surface A at the very left end, I get a CustomEvent on Surface B and a MouseEvent on Surface B.

The above seems to be caused by the z transform. When I reverse the z transform to, obviously Surface B disappears

Surface B is as wide as its radius and has a transform (10, 280, 1)
Surface A's width is 320 and has a transform (0,0,2)

```
    this.surfaceA.on('click', function(e) {
        if (e instanceof CustomEvent) {
            this._eventOutput.emit('select-row', this.obj);
        }
    }.bind(this));

    this.surfaceB.on('click', function(e) {
        if (e instanceof CustomEvent) {
            this._eventOutput.emit('new-event', this.obj);
        } 
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: I've had fast page transitions that where the button was a fraction of second later the input thats there then is clicked as the page loads. I've also had buttons that would click themselves a fraction of a second after I clicked them. Was really annoying when it was my menu button. If this is the type of thing your experiencing let me know I have a fix.

Comment: Is there any way you can show us a jsFiddle or jsBin working example? There is still information missing that would help us to intelligently answer your question. Like, how are you tracking that there was a CustomEvent and MouseEvent on surface B

Answer (score 0):

Update to 0.3.0 seemed to have fixed the issue